# How do create perpetual animation without freezing?

Tags: javascript, animation, while-loop, conditional-statements, infinite-loop

I am still a newbie at Javascript. I tried writing a program to make images fadeToggle all the time, so I used the while conditional statement (combined with a constant variable); after running that and freezing my computer (then remembering that viruses are basically infinite operations) I searched on here a bit, realized I should probably, indeed, never use infinite loops.

(Actually I want shimmer -- meaning to go from opacity 0.9 to 0.6 to 0.9 etc...) so its not the same as fadeToggle, but the same question remains; how do I make it go infinitely?(without writing malicious code.)

This is what I wrote, for your reference:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var always10 = 10;
while (always10 == 10) {
    $('.pimg').fadeToggle(2600);
                   }
});
</script>
```

Also, I've found out on another thread that `while(true)` is better for infinite loops. So another question: are infinite loops *sometimes* OK?

Comment: Inifinite loops are almost never OK in Javascript. It's single-threaded, so you'll never be able to interact with the document. Use `setInterval()` to run a function periodically in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Javascript is asynchornous there is no `sleep` methode. But instead, a good idea is to use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) or [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Without these function, your loop is going to take as most ressources as it can and it can result in a freeze (depending on your browser).

Comment: Asynchornous and sleep mode = goes over my head (I do not speak another programming language so :-P), but the setInterval and setTimeout solves my question. Like another poster, I wanted to write my own, so I didn't go with jquery. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Just use callbacks already provided by jQuery animations like [.fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/):

```
function fadeToggleForever ($e) {
    $e.fadeToggle({
        duration: 2600,
        // start another fadeToggle when this one completes
        complete: function () { fadeToggleForever($e) }
    });
}

// main code
fadeToggleForever($('.pimg'));
```

The of using the complete callback works because jQuery animations internally use `setTimeout` (or perhaps `setInterval`) and thus "yield" code execution so that the browser can continue reacting to user input and updating the display.